# Uniform distance between points

Tags: objective-c, math, geometry, calculus

How could I, having a path defined by several points that are not in a uniform distance from each other, redefine along the same path the same number of points but with a uniform distance. I'm trying to do this in Objective-C with `NSArray`s of `CGPoint`s but so far I haven't had any luck with this.
Thank you for any help.

EDIT

I was wondering if it would help to reduce the number of points, like when detecting if 3 points are collinear we could remove the middle one, but I'm not sure that would help.

EDIT

Illustrating:
Reds are the original points, blues the post processed points:

[image]

The new path defined by the blue dots does not correspond to the original one.

Comment: How are you defining the path?  Line segments?  Polynomial interpolation?  Some sort of spline?

Comment: The path is defined by line segments from one point to another using the CGContextAddLineToPoint function and all the points are saved.

Comment: Do you want the new set of points to be equidistant in **the path created by the line segments between the old points**?

Comment: But your new blue points don't define the same path as the old red ones.  If the blue points are uniformly spaced along the old path they will not be uniformly spaced along the new path.

Comment: @Mark: Exactly my point. I think the new points should be uniform on the old path (defined by the line segments ) but not necessarily uniform on the new path (i.e. the line segments between points in the new path don't have the same length)

Comment: @Jacob @Mack: Yes the new points do not define the same path and they are uniform on the old path and not in the new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is simple and easily solvable actually :)

The basic idea is:

- First check if the distance between your current point (P) and the end point of the line segment you are on is >= the distance between P and the next point (Q).
- If it is, great, we use some simple trigonometry to figure it out.
- Else, we move to the adjacent line segment (in your ordering) and **deduct the distance between P and the endpoint of the line segment you are on** and continue the process.

### Pseudocode:

#### Defined previously

```
struct LineSegment
{
  Point start,end;
  int ID;
  double len; // len = EuclideanDistance(start,end);
  LineSegment *next_segment;
  double theta; // theta = atan2(slope_of_line_segment);
}

Function [LineSegment nextseg] = FindNextLineSegment(LineSegment lineseg)
Input: LineSegment object of the current line segment
Output: LineSegment object of the adjacent line segment in your ordering. 
nextseg.ID = -1 if there are no more segments
```

#### Function: Find the next point along your path

```
Function [Point Q, LineSegment Z] = FindNextPt(Point P, LineSegment lineseg, int dist): 
Input: The current point P, the distance between this point and the next, and the LineSegment of the line segment which contains P.
Output: The next point Q, and the line segment it is on

Procedure:
distToEndpt = EuclideanDistance(P,lineseg->end);
if( distToEndpt >= d )
{
 Point Q(lineseg->start.x + dist*cos(lineseg.theta), lineseg->start.y + dist*sin(lineseg.theta));
 Z = lineseg;
}
else
{
 nextseg = lineseg->next_segment;
    if( nextseg.ID !=-1 )
    {
  [Q, Z] = FindNextPt(nextseg->start,nextseg->ID,dist-distToEndpt);
 }
    else
    {
  return [P,lineseg];
 }
}
 return [Q,Z]
```

#### Entry point

```
Function main()
Output: vector of points
Procedure:

vector<LineSegment> line_segments;
// Define it somehow giving it all the properties
// ....

vector<Point> equidistant_points;
const int d = DIST;

[Q Z] = FindNextPoint(line_segments[0].start,line_segments[0],DIST);
while( Z.ID != -1 )
{
 equidistant_points.push_back(Q);
 [Q Z] = FindNextPt(Q,Z,d);
}
```

Comment: Why does this guarantee that all output edges have uniform length?

Comment: Each point is selected such that it is distant from each other *along the specified path*.

Comment: Right, but equidistant along the old path != equidistant in the plane. So won't the segments you get have nonuniform length?

Comment: Agreed, but is that what the user wants? It seems like the path is fixed and he wants to resample it so that the points are equidistant.

Comment: @Jacob: I don't think so.  I think they want the points to be the same distance along the path.  They don't care about the plane the path is contained on.

Comment: Exactly the points are equidistant along the path not in the plane.

Comment: @Reonarudo: The point **are** equidistant on the **old path** but not the **new path** --- is that OK?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can do what you state that you want to do.  But that could be a misunderstanding on my part.  For example, I have understood from your comment that the path is straight between successive points, not curved.

Take, for example, a simple path of 3 points (0,1,2) and 2 line segments (0-1,1-2) of different lengths.  Leave points 0 and 2 where they are and introduce a new point 1' which is equidistant from points 0 and 2.  If point 1' is on one of the line segments 0-1, 1-2, then one of the line segments 0-1', 1'-2 is not coincident with 0-1, 1-2.  (Easier to draw this, which I suggest you do.)  If point 1' is not on either of the original line segments then the entire path is new, apart from its endpoints.

So, what relationship between the new path and the old path do you want ?

EDIT: more of an extended comment really, like my 'answer' but the comment box is too small.

I'm still not clear how you want to define the new path and what relationship it has to the old path.  First you wanted to keep the same number of points, but in your edit you say that this is not necessary.  You agree that replacing points by new points will shift the path.  Do you want, perhaps, a new path from point 0 to point N-1, defined by N points uniformly spaced on a path which minimises the area between the old and new paths when drawn on the Cartesian plane ?

Or, perhaps you could first define a polynomial (or spline or other simple curve) path through the original points, then move the points to and fro along the curve until they are uniformly spaced ?

Comment: I see what you mean but you could leave the new point 1 over the segment between point 0 and old point 1 or old point 1 and point 2 depending where the middle would belong, maintaining some of the path aspect properties. I'm well aware that it will never be the same path.

Answer (score 1):

My sense is that this is a very hard problem.

It basically amounts to a constrained optimization problem. The objective function measures how close the new line is from the old one. The constraints enforce that the new points are the same distance apart.

Finding a good objective function is the tricky bit, since it must be differentiable, and we don't know ahead of time on which segments each new point will lie: for instance, it's possible for two new points to lie on an extra-long old segment, and no new points lying on some extra-short old segment. If you somehow know a priori on which segments the new points will lie, you can sum the distances between points and their target segments and use that as your objective function (note that this distance function is nontrivial, since the segments are finite: it is composed of three pieces and its level-sets are "pill-shaped.")

Or you might forget about requiring the new points to lie on old segments, and just look for a new polyline that's "close" to the old one. For instance, you might try to write down an L2-like metric between polylines, and use that as your objective function. I don't expect this metric to be pleasant to write down, or differentiate.

Comment: I'm in agreement with you @user168715 and await OP's clarification of what the objective function is, or in other words the desired characteristics of the new path.

Answer (score 0):

This will use quite a bit of vector math but is quite simple really.

First you will need to find the total distance of the path. Depending on how the points of the path are stored is how you will do it. Here is a basic example on a 2 Dimensional Path in Pseudo-code.

```
// This would generally be done with vectors, however I'm not sure
// if you would like to make your own class for them as I do so I will use arrays.

// The collection of points
int Points[4][2] = { {0,0}, {1,2}, {5,4}, {6,5} };
int Points2 = Points;

// goes to 3 because there are 4 points
for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {
     x = Points[i+1][0] - Points[i][0];
     y = Points[i+1][1] - Points[i][1];
     d += sqrt(( x * x ) + ( y * y ));
}

// divide distance by number of points to get uniform distance
dist = d/4;

// now that you have the new distance you must find the points
// on your path that are that far from your current point
// same deal here... goes to 3 because there are 4 points
for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {
     // slope
     m = ( Points[i+1][1] - Points[i][1] ) / ( Points[i+1][0] - Points[i][0] );
     // y intercept
     b = -(M * Points[i][0]) + Points[i][1];
     // processor heavy which makes this problem difficult
     // if some one knows a better way please say something
     // check every degree grabbing the points till one matches
     // if it doesn't then check next segment.
     for(float j=0; j<360; j += 0.1) {
          x = dist * sin(j);
          y = sqrt((dist * dist) - ( x * x ));
          if (y - (M * x + C)) {
               // then the point is on the line so set it
               Points2[i+1][0] = x;
               Points2[i+1][1] = y;
          }
     }
}
```

The last step is what makes it unreasonable but this should work for you.
There may be a small math error somewhere I double checked this several times but there could be something I missed. So if anyone notices something please inform me and I will edit it.

Hope this helps,
Gale

Comment: What do you mean by "all points continuously move away from each other."? The points can move away but can also move closer.

Comment: At first I thought that it might cause an error because it would make the uniform size too small but after reevaluating it I noticed that it will still work. I'm going to edit it to correct that.

Answer (score 0):

I think a perturbative approach will work for this one.

I assume:

1. we know how to slide a point along the path and recalculate the distances (pretty trivial), and

   the end points must remain fixed (otherwise the whole problem becomes trivial).

just iterate over the remaining (n-2) points: if point k is closer to point (k-1) than to point (k+1), move it a little forward along the path. Likewise if it's closer to point (k+1), move a little back along the path.

It's probably best to start with large step sizes (for speed) then make them smaller (for precision). Even if the points pass each other, I think this approach will sort them back into order.